# iTunes Connect Technical Role Access; Pro & Cons as a Developer

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

Our company had contracted out an agency to develop an app. We decided to create an apple developer account and got the agency to transfer out the app to our itunes connect once they had completed the development. I had given them access to manage the application throughout our iTunes Connect and gave them role access as 'Technical'

But they had recently requested us to make them Admin so they can manage our provision profiles so when they ship out more updates to us (not sure if this proper reason or them being sketchy). I am hesitant to make this change because they have access to our apps sales and financial reports (as our app generates revenue on initial app purchase)

Is it a safer to leave the role privilege as-is, 'Technical' and I can simply just provide them the provision profile information if its required? As a developer, what is the pros and cons of having 'Technical' role access? Is there any major limitation?

Comment: Not sure exactly the privileges you get with the "Admin" role in iTunes Connect, but in my book rule #1 is never to give anyone admin or root access unless you would trust them with your own private parts.

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning profiles are created via http://developer.apple.com/ , not iTunes Connect, and as far as I am concerned there are three levels of access over there: Admin / Member / Agent, and this is managed via separate admin panel, which can be found in 'Member Center'.

With 'Technical' privileges in iTC you can do everything needed to perform updates on your app/adding new apps/sending messages to App Review team. The only thing I found missing when compared to 'Admin' account was ability to generate promo codes (of course except of all the sales / iAD / Newsstand subscribers data stuff)